# Why does python sounddevice returns nothing?

Tags: python, wsl-2, python-sounddevice

I'm using wsl version 2 and Xlaunch to connect with x11 server. The problem is when I'm running this code:

```
import sounddevice as sd
print(sd.query_devices())
```

It returns nothing or even running `$python3 -m sounddevice` ,again returns nothing. what can be the problem?

Comment: do you actually have a sound device connected? Could you try connecting some earphones in the audiojack and see if it detects them?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I connected an earphone to my laptop and unfortunately it did not recognize it either

Comment: can you try running it with `sudo`?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki can you type the command on that?

Comment: how is your file called? to execute your file you should do `python3 yourfilename.py`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki oh, its not a file, I'm trying it on jupyter lab

Comment: no, go to console. and execute `python3 yourfilename.py`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried it and yet there is no output

Answer (score 0):

You mention setting up Xlaunch (VcXsrv), but this only provides graphical support, not audio.  PulseAudio is typically used to provide a connection between the Linux code running in WSL and the Windows audio source.

While you can configure PulseAudio manually, I would recommend simply using the WSLg feature of WSL2, since it's now available for both Windows 10 and 11 users.  WSLg should automatically configure PulseAudio for you with no additional effort.

See [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389923/1165986) where I cover how to upgrade your system (hopefully) to the latest Windows release and then upgrade WSL to use the 1.0.0 (or later) application package that includes this support.